# Google Calendar API returning generic Bad Request

Tags: flutter, dart, google-calendar-api

I'm currently struggling with figuring out what's wrong with a Event insert I'm trying to accomplish in Flutter using Google Calendar V3 API. Initially I thought it's a matter of RFC3339 vs ISO8601 date formats, but I'm grasping at straws.

`Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: Bad Request)` is what I'm getting from:

```
   import 'package:googleapis/calendar/v3.dart';
   import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth.dart';
   import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

    ...
    var calendar = await getCalendar();
    var ac = await getOrCreateCredentials();
    var client = await getClient(ac);
    var calendarId = await storage.read(key: "calendar_id");
    var capi = CalendarApi(client);

    EventCreator ec = new EventCreator();
    ec.displayName = "Display Name";

    EventDateTime edt = new EventDateTime();
    int hour = int.parse(ds.hour.split(":")[0]);
    int min = int.parse(ds.hour.split(":")[1]);
    DateTime x = ds.data.add(Duration(hours: hour, minutes: min));
    edt.dateTime = x;
    edt.timeZone = x.timeZoneName;

    EventDateTime edtEnd = new EventDateTime();
    DateTime y = x.add(Duration(hours: 1));
    edtEnd.dateTime = y;
    edtEnd.timeZone = y.timeZoneName;

    Event e = new Event();
    e.created = DateTime.now();
    e.creator = ec;
    e.description = d.var + " \n" + d.var;
    e.summary = "Summary";
    e.etag = d.var;
    e.location = d.var;
    e.start = edt;
    e.end = edtEnd;

    try {
      capi.events.insert(e, calendarId);
```

The full JSON response contains nothing else except `global` domain, `badrequest` and HTTP `400` code.

I also tried `.toUtc()` on the DateTime objects to make them RFC3339 compliant, but still the same error presents.

**Later Edit**

The issue is indeed related to the time, the Dart DateTime class does not format the time in a way Google likes (`2021-04-12T08:30:00+03:00` which I've deduced from other languages' API implementations, and the source code of the package which does a `.toString()` of the DateTime basically).

The way around this is to create the EventDateTime from a JSON object, and to use a hacky Dart extension. I apologize for the naming but it's annoying.

```
extension FuckyDateTime on DateTime {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> fuckyDateTime() {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> x = new Map();
    String formatted = this.year.toString() +
        '-' +
        (this.month.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.month.toString()
            : this.month.toString()) +
        '-' +
        (this.day.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.day.toString()
            : this.day.toString()) +
        'T' +
        (this.hour.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.hour.toString()
            : this.hour.toString()) +
        ':' +
        (this.minute.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.minute.toString()
            : this.minute.toString()) +
        ':' +
        (this.second.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.second.toString()
            : this.second.toString()) +
        '+' +
        '03:00';
    x.putIfAbsent('dateTime', () => formatted);
    x.putIfAbsent('timeZone', () => 'Europe/Bucharest');
    return x;
  }
}
```

and `EventDateTime edt = new EventDateTime.fromJson(x.fuckyDateTime());` where `x` is a `DateTime` object.

Comment: It doesn't seem like anywhere you are getting authorization to access the Calendar API. Do you have an authorized client ? I would suggest heading over to the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) and make sure your `e` matches what the request body looks like. Also could you point to the api client you are using?

Comment: I do have an authorized client but for brevity I didn't paste the full code here, if it were an authentication problem I'd expect a `401` response code instead of the `400` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials).
I did check on that page if my `e` is properly built and it seems to be.

Comment: Added in the question body.

Comment: Well, it's right here [pub.dev/packages/googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis), published by Google. I added the imports in the top of the question code block as well.

Comment: How do you know the order of the arguments is correct here: `capi.events.insert(e, calendarId);`?

Comment: `async.Future<Event> insert(Event request, core.String calendarId,
      {core.int conferenceDataVersion,`
Class definition, it would simply fail before running otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I can't tell what the issue is still. It could help if you paste your `e` object removing any sensitive data

Comment: What is `d.var`? Where is the object `d`?

Comment: I'm sorry but that literally does not matter in the slightest, consider it a random string. Description, etag and location accept strings.

Comment: Well since `var` is a keyword, I thought it may be messing up your request somehow.

Comment: No, they were other properties but I changed them to `var` for the example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230863/discussion-between-codin-moldovanu-and-aerials).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is indeed related to the time, the Dart DateTime class does not format the time in a way Google likes (`2021-04-12T08:30:00+03:00` which I've deduced from other languages' API implementations, and the source code of the package which does a `.toString()` of the DateTime basically). Fair mention that Dart DateTime does provide a `String` of ISO8601, Google wants an `RFC3339` compliant date.

The way around this is to create the EventDateTime from a JSON object, and to use a hacky Dart extension. I apologize for the naming but it's annoying.

```
extension FuckyDateTime on DateTime {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> fuckyDateTime() {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> x = new Map();
    String formatted = this.year.toString() +
        '-' +
        (this.month.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.month.toString()
            : this.month.toString()) +
        '-' +
        (this.day.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.day.toString()
            : this.day.toString()) +
        'T' +
        (this.hour.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.hour.toString()
            : this.hour.toString()) +
        ':' +
        (this.minute.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.minute.toString()
            : this.minute.toString()) +
        ':' +
        (this.second.toString().length == 1
            ? '0' + this.second.toString()
            : this.second.toString()) +
        '+' +
        '03:00';
    x.putIfAbsent('dateTime', () => formatted);
    x.putIfAbsent('timeZone', () => 'Europe/Bucharest');
    return x;
  }
}
```

and `EventDateTime edt = new EventDateTime.fromJson(x.fuckyDateTime());` where `x` is a `DateTime` object.